# I almost stalled and my oil light came on

Tags: oil, stall, warning-light

I was driving along this evening and lifted the clutch too quickly by mistake. I have hardly ever done this (about twice a year)

However, this time the engine revs dropped to about 100-200rpm, and the oil light flashed on for about 1/4 of a second. The engine was warm at the time. Then the engine revved back up to idle speed.

Have I done any damage by doing this?

What should I do if I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue with your vehicle or its engine. Most vehicle manufacturers have set the "idiot light" to come on if the oil pressure drops below ~5psi. Obviously you've hit that threshold. Oil remains on parts for a fairly decent amount of time even if there isn't any oil flow. It doesn't take long for the oil to be gone. You'll have caused more damage during a dry start (where the engine hasn't been ran in a few days and all of the oil is at the bottom of the oil pan) than you would here ... even though that doesn't cause much damage either (most engine wear occurs at startup due to this). When the oil is changed your oil pressure light will stay on longer than you described. Again, you will have done no real damage to the engine in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have done no damage. The light was indicating low oil pressure, but a brief moment like that will not be a problem.  Never ignore the oil pressure light if it stays on even if you think you will be home in a few minutes. It doesn't take long driving with no oil to getting to the moving parts to cause damage.  In the second or so that you experienced, there would have been oil remaining where it was needed.